# Jenkins tool installation fails with message: Installer "Run Shell Command" cannot be used to install "<some tool>" on the node "<some node name>"

Tags: jenkins

I have configured Jenkins using **Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration** to ensure that agents have the required tool chain installed before they work on builds.

Why is a pipline build's tool-installation stage failing with the following error (for example)?

```
Installer "Run Shell Command" cannot be used to install "jdk-11.0.5" on the node "cent76-test401"
```

Answer (score 2):

This error message can be returned when the Jenkins configuration for the tool installation is set to run only on certain labels, and your target agent does not have the required label.

In the question's example, the JDK installation's Run Shell Command configuration was limited to agents with the `lin64` label, but the agent named cent76-test401 did not have this label.

*See also* timestamp 15:25:56 in this #jenkins IRC log https://echelog.com/logs/browse/jenkins/1487545200